# Improper integral associated with Basel problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, sums-of-squares

I was looking at [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1170722/193591) And I thought there should be a relation between $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sinh^2(x)}dx$ and ${\pi}^2$. After dividing by ${\pi}^2$ I noticed that it is the sum of the square of natural numbers. Looks like there is a relation between $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{\sinh^2(x)}dx$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k}$ and I have no clue how to prove it.

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Have you tried replicating the computation in the link and then generalizing it?

Comment: Yes, The problem is when sinh(x) is squared in the denominator, after expanding $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ I can't use geometric series the same way.

Comment: You would really wan to expand your comment and actually update your original question so that other users can see what you have thought, tried, and was struggling with. For me, adapting the computation in the link seems a straightforward task (together with the knowledge that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-ax}\,\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(s)a^{-s}$ for $s, a>0$). So, we would very love to see why you are having trouble doing so.

Comment: See [Answers to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284185/integrate-int-infty-infty-fracx-sinh-xdx/4552104#4552104)

Comment: [mark-viola](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/218419/mark-viola) I am not sure how to move to $\sinh^2(x)$ in denominator.

Comment: The antiderivative does exist in terms of polylogarithms

Comment: @mike: $1/\sinh^2 x=4e^{-2x}/(1-e^{-2x})^2$ can be handled with $(1-z)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)z^n$ (for $|z|<1$); $\color{white}{\text{the same for higher powers}}$. Another option is just integration by parts. And many, many other alternatives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Metamorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543769/metamorphy) You can use $1/\sinh^2 x=4e^{-2x}/(1-e^{-2x})^2
$ and $ (1-z)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)z^n $ to write the integral as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{\sinh^2(x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^k\frac{4e^{-2x}}{(1-e^{-2x})^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}4e^{-2x}x^k\frac{1}{(1-e^{-2x})^2}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}4e^{-2x}x^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)e^{-2nx}dx$$
Which is:

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4e^{-2x}x^k(n+1)e^{-2nx}dx
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4x^k(n+1)e^{-(2n+2)x}dx$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4(n+1)\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ke^{-(2n+2)x}dx$$
Now by using properties of Gamma function mentioned above
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-ax}\,\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(s)a^{-s}
 $$
You can write:
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4(n+1)\Gamma(k+1)(2n+2)^{-(k+1)}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}k!\frac{4(n+1)}{(n+1)^{k+1}2^{k+1}}
=\frac{4\cdot k!}{2^{k+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k}}\\\\
=\frac{ k!}{2^{k-1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{k}}$$